# After deployment image not change

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

After deployment first time image display and same page next time change the imageurl old image only is there new image not display. this is code i want change anything in code....

```
protected void btn_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image1.Dispose();   
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesignNo.Text))
        {
            Image1.Visible = true;
            Image1.Dispose();
            Image1.ImageUrl = string.Empty;
            filename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("") + "\\Images" + "\\" + txtDesignNo.Text + ".jpg";
            // filename =CGlobals.imagePath +  txtDesignNo.Text + ".jpg";
            // string filename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("") + "\\ImageStorage" + "\\" + 1 + ".jpg";
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(filename);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Masters/Images/" + txtDesignNo.Text + ".jpg";
            // Image1.ImageUrl =CGlobals.imagePath + txtDesignNo.Text + ".jpg";
            //Image1.ImageUrl = filename;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you have tried clearing your browser cache and it is indeed serving out the old image, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Try shift+f5 to force a full refresh.  Depending on your browser, this might force the fetching of the new image instead of using the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you save the image under \Images\ but then you try to show it from \Masters\Images.

Try changing the upload path to match the imageurl or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the image path using **firebug**. You saved image to image folder, but you are accessing from master\images.